# Is there an estimate of the number of enterocytes in the human body?

Tags: human-biology, gastroenterology

I've been looking for this information but I haven't been able to find it. Does anyone know if there are estimates of the number of enterocytes or epithelial cells in the intestinal tract? Otherwise, would a simple division of the volumes of the intestinal tract and of a cell work as a rough estimation?

Comment: Difficult to estimate given the considerable variation in human gut length. Related post: [Does variation in human gut length vary predictably with diet of ancestors?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43845/16866)

Comment: It might be easier to estimate the density of some small area and try scaling up based on length and other volume measures. However using such a model to do so would require density estimates from each variable segment. For example, as circular folds decrease in robustness from duodenum to ileum and eventually disappear in the colon, I would expect cell density to decline dramatically

Comment: Why are you asking? General interest (and therefore requiring low precision) or for perhaps some sort of metabolic calculation(and therefore requiring greater accuracy)?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure to what degree localized cell densities (e.g., of the duodenum lets say) vary between people. I think a more answerable question underlying yours that must be addressed in any answer you ultimately receive is whether and to what degree cell density of given anatomical regions varies between people

Comment: @theforestecologist I just want an approximate range for modeling purposes. But as the other comments have pointed out, this seems to vary significantly from person to person.

Comment: It might help if you explained why you wish to know something that on the face of it has the intellectual content of the Guinness Book of Records.